# Android: Custom Button Constructor getting null Context on Huawei devices

Tags: java, android

We have a CustomButton that inherits from your regular Android Button. For some reason, a null context is passed in the constructor on Huawei devices, causing the app to crash. Any idea why? Here's the crash dump:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.project.test/com.project.test.FullscreenActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error
>   inflating class sdk.project.widget.ProjectButton at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2078)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2103)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1211)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4842) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) Caused by:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error
>   inflating class sdk.project.widget.ProjectButton at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
>   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
>   at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867) at
>   com.project.test.FullscreenActivity.onCreate(FullscreenActivity.java:43)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5010) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2042)
>   ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) ... 23
>   more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:242)
>   at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
>   at sdk.project.data.ProjectDbManager.(ProjectDbManager.java:38) at
>   sdk.project.data.ProjectDbManager.getInstance(ProjectDbManager.java:26)
>   at
>   sdk.project.widget.ProjectButtonHelper.initializeState(ProjectButtonHelper.java:367)
>   at
>   sdk.project.widget.ProjectButton.setInitialButtonState(ProjectButton.java:153)
>   at
>   sdk.project.widget.ProjectButton.initializeButton(ProjectButton.java:137)
>   at sdk.project.widget.ProjectButton.(ProjectButton.java:119) ... 26
>   more

Comment: Are you sure it is that the context is null and not something else? Is the database NPE caused by a null context?

Comment: Yes, the database NPE is caused by a null context